# ImproperlyConfigured at /watchlist-detail/1 Could not resolve Url for hyperlinked relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```py
from .models import WatchList,StreamPlatform
from rest_framework import serializers


class WatchListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=WatchList
        fields='__all__'


class StreamPlatformSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=StreamPlatform
        fields='__all__'
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls  import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.WatchListAV.as_view()),
    path("watchlist-detail/<int:pk>",views.WatchListDetailsAV.as_view()),

]
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from .models import WatchList,StreamPlatform
from .serializers import WatchListSerializer,StreamPlatformSerializer
from rest_framework import status


class WatchListAV(APIView):
    
    def get(self,request):
        # print(self)
        # print("1")
        movies=WatchList.objects.all()
        # print("1")
        
        serializer=WatchListSerializer(movies,many=True,context={'request': request})
        print(request)
        # print(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self,request):
        serializer=WatchListSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)

class WatchListDetailsAV(APIView):
    def put(self,request,pk):
            try:
                movies=WatchList.objects.get(pk=pk)
            except:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            serializer=WatchListSerializer(movies,data=request.data)
            print("1")
            if serializer.is_valid():
                print("2")
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
            return Response({"error":"Data invalid format"},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self,request,pk):
        try:
            movie=WatchList.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except WatchList.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'error':"movie not found"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer=WatchListSerializer(movie,context={'request': request})
        print(request)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def delete(self,request,pk):
        movie=WatchList.objects.get(pk=pk)
        movie.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

    
class WatchList(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    storyline=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am beginner and I am unable to understand this error.I have searched for solution at different places but not found any solution.

I am getting this error.

> "ImproperlyConfigured at / Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked
> relationship using view name "watchlist-detail". You may have failed
> to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured
> the `lookup_field` attribute on this field."

Answer (score 0):

It is because of [`How hyperlinked views are determined`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined), you seem to have grasped this concept as you set your `URL path` as `watchlist-detail`. But, what the framework expect is that the `view name` be in this model, so:

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("watchlist/",views.WatchListAV.as_view()),
    path("watchlist-detail/<int:pk>/",views.WatchListDetailsAV.as_view(), name='watchlist-detail'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks I got the solution.Actually i did not add the url field in both the serializer as i was using hyprlinkedmodel serializer